# Bash grep output in addition to echo within if statement

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a simple script that checks if images are being used within our `html` directory.  I have a file called **imageserver.txt** which looks like:

```
imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_tumblr.png
imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_gaf.png
imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_yelp.png
imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_linkedin.png
.....
```

This is my simple script

**imageSearch.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r var
do

echo "\n ... Searching for $var \n"

if grep -rq $var /var/www/html; then

    echo "Image exists ...\n"
    echo $var >> doesExist.txt

else

    echo "Image does not exist ...\n"
    echo $var >> nonExists.txt

fi

done < ./imageserver.txt
```

Now, this works GREAT. I am wanting to add one more element only to the `if` statement.  I want the `echo >>` to not only print `$var` to the  `doesExist.txt` -- But what **file** it was found in ..  I am thinking I may need a secondary `grep` inside the `if`?

My desired input into `doesExist.txt` would look like:

```
imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_tumblr.png  |  /var/www/html/file1.html
imageserver/icons/socialmedia/sqcolor_tumblr.png  |  /var/www/html/file2.html
```

I am stuck and not quite sure if I need a secondary `grep` or -- Is it possible I can get the file names from the original `grep` within the original `if` statement?

How do I accomplish my desired input into `doesExist.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
if grep -rq $var /var/www/html; then

    echo "Image exists ...\n"
    echo $var >> doesExist.txt
```

to some variation of:

```
results=$(grep -rH "$var" /var/www/html)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

    echo "Image exists ...\n"
    echo "$results" >> doesExist.txt
```

Comment: Excellent --  I replaced the `-H` (--with-filename) with `-l` ( --files-with-matches) and double bracketed the `if`  solved!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: in addition ... The `if [[ $?` is a lifesaver ..  I probably never would have come across that just researching this specific problem--  Thanks again.